# Can't get php 5.4 on Ubuntu 10.04 lts plesk 10

Tags: php, ubuntu-10.04, plesk

I'm working in linux ubuntu 10.04 It's for the first time together with parallels plesk 10.4.4.

Parallels plesk only comes with php 5.3 and I really need php 5.4 .

Is it possible to install php 5.4 directly on my ubunut vps then plesk will use it?

Or do I need to do something with plesk?

Thanks!

Comment: Ubuntu 10.04? That version is three years old.

Comment: Off-topic. Try [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/) or [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/).

Comment: @Blender It might be three years old, but it's a long term supported operating system up to 2015. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LTS

Answer (score 1):

Plesk don't comes with php on Ubuntu. Plesk installs PHP from available repositories registered in apt.

So, you should find out how to upgrade PHP on ubuntu and that's all. As I know plesk don't have any restrictions if current PHP version will be upgraded.

Just one of guides from Google: https://serverfault.com/questions/420286/how-do-i-upgrade-from-php-5-3-to-php-5-4-6-in-ubuntu